# Magento 2 PWA stripe payment

Tags: magento2.3.4, pwa-studio, stripe

I have configured PWA studio with Magento 2. Now, I want to know how to implement stripe payment integration with the PWA storefront? Could you please provide any guidance on how can I implement this?

Comment: Hi @Mahesh I am also looking for same

Answer (score 0):

To implement Stripe payment integration with the PWA storefront, you can use the Stripe API and a Stripe payment module for Magento 2.

Here are the general steps to integrate Stripe payment with the PWA storefront:

- Install a Stripe payment module for Magento 2: First, you need to install a Stripe payment module for Magento 2. You can find many Stripe payment modules in the Magento Marketplace. Once you have installed the module, configure it with your Stripe API keys.
- Add the Stripe payment method to the PWA storefront: In the PWA storefront, you can add the Stripe payment method by modifying the payment method configuration file. You will need to create a new payment method file for the Stripe payment method and include the necessary configuration details, such as the API keys.
- Modify the checkout page: To display the Stripe payment method on the checkout page, you will need to modify the checkout page in your PWA storefront. You will need to add the necessary HTML and JavaScript code to display the Stripe payment form and handle the payment submission.
- Test the integration: After completing the above steps, test the integration by placing an order using the Stripe payment method.

Please note that the implementation process may vary depending on the specific Stripe payment module and PWA storefront that you are using. You may need to refer to the documentation of your payment module and PWA storefront to complete the integration.